# Maxscale, ranks and priority

Tags: galera, mariadb-10.4, maxscale

I'm using a maxscale (6.2) readwritesplit router with 3 galera servers (mariadb 10.4). 2 of them are in DC1, and a 3rd one is on a distant DC2.

Using [ranks](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-6-readwritesplit/#server-ranks) is the only option I see here, as `priority` will be used by galeramon to select the master.

My goal is to tell maxscale to use DC1 as much as possible, so server1 as master (priority=1, rank=primary), server2 as slave (priority=2, rank=primary), and use DC2 server3 **only if** server1 or server2 are not reachable (priority=3, rank=secondary).

Is this the correct behavior?

```
[server1]
type=server
address=192.168.0.11
priority=1
rank=primary

[server2]
type=server
address=192.168.0.12
priority=2
rank=primary

[server3]
type=server
address=192.168.0.21
priority=3
rank=secondary

[split]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=server1,server2,server3

[monitor]
type=monitor
module=galeramon
servers=server1,server2,server3
root_node_as_master=true
use_priority=true
```

Comment: You don't need `root_node_as_master=true` if you use priorities as the priority mechanism overrides all other monitoring logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the readwritesplit module [only uses connections that have the same `rank`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-6-readwritesplit/#server-ranks). This means that if both `server1` and `server2` fail, the readwritesplit service will use `server3` as long as it is up.

When either of the two other servers comes back up, the galeramon monitor will shift the `Master` label from `server3` to one of the other nodes. At that point readwritesplit will discard the connection to `server3` and reconnect to the nodes with the higher rank, if possible.

Comment: Thanks markus. What happens if server2 fails? Will server1 get reads and writes, or will writes go to server1 and reads to server3?

Comment: All traffic will go to server1 at that point.